# redirect to the same file as the source file processed by the command

Tags: io-redirection

1. Redirection is not allowed here. Is `cat` not allowing? But isn't
   redirection independent of any command running with it?

   ```
   $ cat bk > bk
   cat: bk: input file is output file
   ```
2. Why does the following redirect empty the file:

   ```
   $ less  bk > bk
   ```

   `awk` also works in the similar way as `less` in regard to redirection. `awk` is the one with which I actually found the problem, while the above examples are meaningless

In general, what are the right way to use redirect?

Comment: May `cat bk |tee bk` or `less bk |tee bk` help you? (in general `<text-processing-command> file1 |tee file1`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the output redirection kills the file before `less` is even started:

```
open("file", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
dup2(3, 1)                        = 1
close(3)                          = 0
execve("/usr/bin/less", ["less", "-WNS", "file"], [/* 102 vars */]) = 0
```

The normal output redirection overwrites the file. The `O_TRUNC` (see `man 2 open`) deletes the file content.