# Redirection not overwriting file but just producing a blank one

Tags: shell

I have a command that strives to just read a file and then comment out every single line in it indiscriminately, then overwrite the existing file.

```
cat file | sed 's/^/#/g' > file
```

But to my surprise this doesn't actually work and actually just produces a blank file. From my understanding of pipes this shouldn't happen given that stdout goes to sed, is processed by sed and then sent to the file. So I'd like to know why this is happening

In place of my expected behavior I implemented a workaround.

```
cat file | sed 's/^/#/g' > /tmp/file; mv /tmp/file file
```

Why does my does my original solution not work though?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I read and write to the same file in Linux without overwriting it?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36261/23408)

Comment: ... Also [redirect to the same file as the source file processed by the command](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165989/23408).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your original solution does not work because as soon as you redirect, the shell creates an empty file by that name.  You can use the `-i` option of `sed` to fix this problem.  For example,

```
sed -i 's/^/#/g' file
```